# How to force clang to check semantic with system(ubuntu) STL header instead of clang's

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, vim, clang

when I try to use clang++ to detect semantic 
My program can be compiled with gcc. when I use clang to detect semantic, I got:

> error| no viable overloaded '*='

problem occurs from one header I include from open source project

```
std::vector<double> Hc;
checksum(H,Hc);
Hc*=1.0/mrpt::math::maximum(Hc);
```

I think the problem is because the clang's STLib headers are different with my Ubuntu's C++ headers, and they didn't override`*=` opt. I added

```
 -std=c++11 
 -stdlib=libc++11 
 -nodefaultlibs
```

and tried this http://libcxx.llvm.org but the only error still there.
Indeed, I am trying `YouCompleteMe` plugin in `vim`. This plugin only need compile semantic and without linking step. and I can't change the header. `'-isystem` doesn't solve the problem'
What should I do to force clang to check semantic with system STL header instead of clang's?

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) doesn't *have* a `*=` operator. Maybe the open-source project have its own overloaded operator?

Answer (score 0):

For the records, this was indeed a bug in the headers of MRPT, which was solved recently. So, it is not the fault of clang++, in fact the newer gcc 6.0 also detected the error.